# Executando WebSocket direto na classe php

Tags: php

Estou iniciando agora com websocket, desenvolvi um chat em realtime usando a biblioteca Ratchet, gostaria se existe alguma forma de inicializar o websocket sem necessidade de executar comando pelo terminal.

Eu vi na documentação o comando:

```
<?php 

$app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
$app->route('/chat', new MyChat);
$app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o ambiente de desenvolvimento, o comando é a forma mais simples para executar. É preciso de alguma forma ter o processo sendo executado em paralelo para escutar as requisições enviadas.

Uma alternativa seria criar um ambiente como se fosse um ambiente em produção usando *supervisord*, como apontado na [documentação do Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy).

Comment: Eu queria o websocket rodando somente quando executar a rota de chat, pois acho que não teria necessidade de roda-lo o tempo todo. Desculpa se estou falando besteira, mas não entendo muito de websocket

Comment: São dois serviços rodando de forma independente e que interagem através de http. Imagine que são dois servidores em sua maquina. Um é o apache ou ngnix para o servidor web que é executado em forma de serviço. O webserver está rodando, independente de vc estar usando ou não. Com o websocket é a mesma lógica ao rodar sob o supervisor

Comment: Entendi @gmsantos, gostei da sugestão